# How can I recreate the Elite: Dangerous Thargoid wormhole?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I’ve seen a cinematic with Thargoids and they have they dark blurry wormhole and I’d like to recreate it but I can’t seem too. Smoke sims are my best option but they don’t work that well for it.[image]

Answer (score 4):

To me it looks like the basic shape could be achieved with a high resolution mesh and some displacement.

I started with a cube and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier which I apllied, then I added another *Subdivision Surface* modifier, a *Displacement* modifier with a larger *Cloud* texture, more subdivisions, another *Displacement* modifier with a smaller *Cloud* texture.

Placing some random icospheres with an emission material inbetween the displaced mesh gave me this result, of course this could need some more tweaking (the light in the original seem to be placed in holes or tunnels for example):

[image: wormhole]

This is how it looks in the viewport:

[image: wormhole solid view]

And this is the modifier stack and the first and the second *Cloud* texture:

[image: modifiers]

My model has a dark grey surface, the original looks like it is a bit brighter. And maybe you could also tweak the roughness, add some subsurface scattering or transmission in the *Principled BSDF* as well...

Comment: It may be hard to see the actual wormhole but that mesh is the Thargoid itself, there’s a dark patch around it and that’s the wormhole.

Comment: @Cabbage Oh I'm sorry, I couldn't recognize that in the first image... I thought the Thargoid was what you wanted to create. Maybe I should delete this answer.

Comment: Oh no don’t delete it, I could use it in the future some time